# Pass a ng-template element to a directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular-directive

I'm trying to pass a `ng-template` to my directive, something like this:

**component.html**

```html
<div myDirective [myTemplate]="myTemplate"></div>
<ng-template #myTemplate><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></ng-template>
```

**directive.ts**

```js
import {Directive, Input} from "@angular/core"

@Directive({
  selector: "[myDirective]"
})
export class MyDirective {
  @Input() myTemplate

  ngOnInit () {
    console.log(this.myTemplate.elementRef.nativeElement)
  }
}
```

But it just shows `<!-- -->`. How do I access the contents of the template? None of the other properties seem to have it - comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505388/access-elementref-inside-a-ng-template-contained-in-a-directive) suggest using `templateRef` instead, but it's undefined.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbhh39) if needed.

To clarify, the ultimate goal of the directive is to conditionally add the contents of the template to its parent element (along with some other changes).

Comment: you should use it as `*myTemplate` instead of `[myTemplate]` that way the structural directive receives what you intend. If you try to use a template inside I suggest @ContentChild or some sort. Not posting as answer as its not

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli Then I get "Can't bind to 'myTemplate' since it isn't a known property of 'div'." And `@ContentChild` doesn't do what I want, I want the template to be reusable so it has to be accessible from outside the directive.

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to achieve. Are you trying to get a reusable template that your directive will inject(?), or are you trying to pass to the directive a template that will do something?

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli The ultimate goal of the directive is to conditionally add the contents of the template to its parent element (along with some other changes).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) :

The ng-template is an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is never displayed directly. In fact, before rendering the view, Angular replaces the ng-template and its contents with a comment.

So at the runtime, ng-template is just a comment. It is not renderable as a DOM and it's impossible to reach it as ElementRef type.

But if you want to send for example a p element to your directive, it's possible. I changed your code to do that. See this stackblitz project:

[https://stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1yt6u?file=src/app/my.directive.ts)

Comment: I know it works with regular elements, but I need to use a template because I don't want it to render in the parent component. I may just have to do that and use CSS to hide it or something if there's no way to do it with a template, but it isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I have a popup-directive to handle positioning of popups in the dom.
I place the directive on a button or link and pass it the popup element. The directive then positions the popup in the dom.

The directive supports both a regular html element and a ng-template element as a popup.

For clarity, the code below contains only parts relevant for the question.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
    
    
@Directive({
    selector: '[ui-popup]'
})
export class UIPopupDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private containerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() popupTemplate: HTMLElement;
  @Input() popupNgTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() data:any;
  
  ngOnInit() {
     if (this.popupNgTemplate) {
      const embeddedViewRef = this.containerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.popupNgTemplate, {
        item: this.data
      });
      embeddedViewRef.detectChanges();
      this.popupTemplate = embeddedViewRef.rootNodes[0];
    }
}
```

Examples of usage:

```
<button type="button" ui-popup [popupTemplate]="regularTag">Click to say hello</button>

<div #regularTag>Hello</div>
```

... or ...

```
<button type="button" ui-popup [popupNgTemplate]="ngTemplateTag">Click to discover the world</button>

<ng-template #ngTemplateTag><div>World</div></ng-template>
```