# Angular: Access elementRef inside an ng-template

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I got a component that renders different form-field components via `ng-template`. Now I want to access a function inside the last rendered component.

I tried accessing it with the `ViewChildren()` annotation with the string selector or the BaseClass all field-components (text-field, select-field) extend from.

`allFields` is always empty. Also tried accessing it as `ContentChildren` and the `AfterContentInit` lifecycle hook. Any Ideas how to achieve this?

It's much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505388/access-elementref-inside-a-ng-template-contained-in-a-directive) question, but it is still unanswered so I thought I'll ask it again. Thanks

`HTML`

```html
<div *ngFor="let field of fields; fieldIndex as index">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="getTemplate()"></ng-container>
</div>
<input type="button" (click)="doFunctionOnLastField()">

<ng-template #text>
 <text-field #field [field]=this.fields[fieldIndex]></text-field>
<ng-template>

<ng-template #select>
 <select-field #field [field]=this.fields[fieldIndex]></text-field>
<ng-template>
```

`TypeScript`

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

 @Input() fields: FieldBase[];
 @ViewChild('text') text: TemplateRef<any>
 @ViewChild('select') select: TemplateRef<any>
 @ViewChildren('field') allFields;

 lastField: FieldBaseComponent;
 fieldIndex: number = 0;

 ngOnInit(): void {
  //...
 }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.lastField = this.allFields.last; //this.allFields is empty
 }

 getTemplate() {
  // returns my template
 }

 doFunctionOnLastField() {
  this.lastField.someFunctionInsideTheField(); //this.lastField... is undefined
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rendered view and its children are only accessible when the template is rendered in the `ViewContainerRef`, so [right here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_template_outlet.ts#L71).

The rendered view cannot be obtained when usin `ngTemplateOutlet`, so i think your best bet is to copy the code and modify it to fit your requirements.

Comment: I changed the structure in my project a bit and worked with angulars event emitter to achieve the behavior I wanted. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The `getTemplate()` method would be called before `ngAfterViewInit()` is called.

When `getTemplate()` is called for the 1st time, it won't even return the TemplateRef, and it's only during next change detection cycle, the TemplateRef would be correctly returned and your fields would be rendered. Chances are that you may even get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error.

So when `ngAfterViewInit` is called, your fields wouldn't have been rendered and hence `this.allFields.last` would be undefined.

Try to specify the `static` metadata property as `true` for the `text` and `select`  ViewChild declarations:

```ts
@ViewChild('text', { static: true }) text: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('select', { static: true }) select: TemplateRef<any>;
```